# Get all background properties from one element and paste to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way(jQuery) to get all background properties from one element and to paste to another. Im trying with something like this:

```
$('body').css({
    'background': $('.app').css('background')
});
```

But this will not work because shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported in jQuery.

This will work:

```
$('body').css({
    'background': $('.app').css('background-image')
});
```

But im pulling background properties from DB, and sometime for background i have image, sometimes just color.

Comment: Your examples are both the same... But why don't you use CSS classes for this?

Comment: Have you tried `$('body')[0].style.background`?

Comment: Edited, now they are not the same.

Comment: The first one works. At least works here: `$('body').css('background', $('pre:eq(1)').css('background'))`